# How to make table stored in local storage persistent when page reloads

Tags: javascript, arrays, web, frontend, web-frontend

im new to programing so please pardon my mistakes.i dynamically created a table using javascript and it works well but when i refresh or reload the page the table dissapers although all values are still stored in the local storage so when i add another value, the new value is appended to the table's prexistng values which is great.however i am trying to make the table persistent even when the page is refreshed or reloaded in such a way that the table is always displayed and the dynamically added values,rows and cells won't vanish when the page is reloaded.i'm trying to do this without any backend. 
this is a link of the actual webapp please use a laptop to view i havent started working on making it responsive https://chidera-codes.github.io/Banky-webapp/
i will add my code below

```
function showData() {
getData();

let table = document.getElementById("accounts_table");
var x = table.rows.length;
while (--x){
table.deleteRow(x);
}

for(i = 0 ; i < array.length; i++){
var row= document.createElement("tr");
var td1 = document.createElement("td");
var td2 = document.createElement("td");
var td3 = document.createElement("td");  
var td4 = document.createElement("td"); 
var td5 = document.createElement("td"); 
var td6 = document.createElement("td");


td1.innerHTML = array[i].date;
td2.innerHTML  = array[i].account_number ;
td3.innerHTML  = array[i].input_account_type;
td4.innerHTML = array[i].account_status;
td5.innerHTML  = array[i].input_open_account;
td6.innerHTML  = array[i].current_balance ;
row.appendChild(td1);
row.appendChild(td2);
row.appendChild(td3);
row.appendChild(td4);
row.appendChild(td5);
row.appendChild(td6);
table.children[0].appendChild(row);

}


};

let array = new Array();
function addData(){
array = getData();
getData();
var today  = new Date(); 
array.push({
date:today.toLocaleDateString("en-US"),
account_number :Math.floor ('22'  + Math.random() * 100000000),
input_account_type:document.getElementById("input_account_type").value,
account_status :'Draft',
input_open_account :' ₦' + document.getElementById("input_open_account").value + ".00",
current_balance : ' ₦' + "0.00"

});
localStorage.setItem('accountData', JSON.stringify(array));
showData();
return false;
};

function getData() {
var str = localStorage.getItem('accountData');
if(str != null){
return JSON.parse(str);
}  
};
```

Comment: welcome , If you want add and edit row of multi rows table , I suggest to you use indexdDB replace of localStorage , check this document : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/IndexedDB_API/Using_IndexedDB

Comment: thanks alot for this information i will check it out right away

Comment: Your welcome , If that comment useful for you, please click on triangle of left side of comment

Answer (score 1):

```html
    <html>
    <head>
    <title>test</title>
    <style>
      th,
      td,
      table {
        border: 1px solid black;
        text-align: center;
      }
    </style>
    </head>
    <body onload="loadTable()">
    <button onclick="addData()">Add Data</button>
    <label>Account Type</label>
    <input id="input_account_type" value="" />
    <label>Open Account</label>
    <input id="input_open_account" value="" />
    <table id="accounts_table"></table>
    </body>
    <script>
    let array = getData();

    let table = document.getElementById("accounts_table");

    const tableHeaders = [
      "Date",
      "Account number",
      "Input account type",
      "Account status",
      "Input open account",
      "Current Balance",
    ];

    const today = new Date();

    const loadTable = () => {
      table.append(getTableHeaderRow());
      showData();
    };

    function showData() {
      array.forEach((accountData) => {
        addToTable(accountData);
      });
    }

    const getTableHeaderRow = () => {
      const row = getTR();
      tableHeaders.forEach((header) => {
        row.append(getTH(header));
      });
      return row;
    };

    const getTR = () => {
      return document.createElement("tr");
    };

    const getTH = (tableHeaderName) => {
      const th = document.createElement("th");
      th.innerHTML = tableHeaderName;
      return th;
    };

    const getTD = (tdValue) => {
      const td = document.createElement("td");
      td.innerHTML = tdValue;
      return td;
    };

    function addData() {
      const newAccountData = {
        date: today.toLocaleDateString("en-US"),
        account_number: Math.floor("22" + Math.random() * 100000000),
        input_account_type: document.getElementById("input_account_type").value,
        account_status: "Draft",
        input_open_account:
          document.getElementById("input_open_account").value + ".00$",
        current_balance: "0.00$",
      };

      array.push(newAccountData);

      addToTable(newAccountData);

      localStorage.setItem("accountData", JSON.stringify(array));
    }

    const addToTable = (newAccountData) => {
      const row = getTR();
      Object.keys(newAccountData).forEach((key) => {
        row.append(getTD(newAccountData[key]));
      });
      table.append(row);
    };

    function getData() {
      var str = localStorage.getItem("accountData");
      if (str != null) {
        return JSON.parse(str);
      }
    }
    </script>
    </html>
```

```js
let array;

let table;

const tableHeaders = [
  "Date",
  "Account number",
  "Input account type",
  "Account status",
  "Input open account",
  "Current Balance",
];

const today = new Date();

function loadTable() {
  array = getData();
  table = document.getElementById("accounts_table");
  console.log(table);
  table.append(getTableHeaderRow());
  showData();
};

function showData() {
  array.forEach((accountData) => {
    addToTable(accountData);
  });
}

const getTableHeaderRow = () => {
  const row = getTR();
  tableHeaders.forEach((header) => {
    row.append(getTH(header));
  });
  return row;
};

const getTR = () => {
  return document.createElement("tr");
};

const getTH = (tableHeaderName) => {
  const th = document.createElement("th");
  th.innerHTML = tableHeaderName;
  return th;
};

const getTD = (tdValue) => {
  const td = document.createElement("td");
  td.innerHTML = tdValue;
  return td;
};

function addData() {

  const newAccountData = {
    date: today.toLocaleDateString("en-US"),
    account_number: Math.floor("22" + Math.random() * 100000000),
    input_account_type: document.getElementById("input_account_type").value,
    account_status: "Draft",
    input_open_account: document.getElementById("input_open_account").value + ".00$",
    current_balance: "0.00$",
  };

  array.push(newAccountData);

  addToTable(newAccountData);

  localStorage.setItem("accountData", JSON.stringify(array));
}

const addToTable = (newAccountData) => {
  const row = getTR();
  Object.keys(newAccountData).forEach((key) => {
    row.append(getTD(newAccountData[key]));
  });
  table.append(row);
};

function getData() {
  var str = localStorage.getItem("accountData");
  if (str != null) {
    return JSON.parse(str);
  }
}
```

```css
th,
td,
table {
  border: 1px solid black;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <title>test</title>
</head>

<body onload="loadTable()">
  <button onclick="addData()">Add Data</button>
  <label>Account Type</label>
  <input id="input_account_type" value="" />
  <label>Open Account</label>
  <input id="input_open_account" value="" />
  <table id="accounts_table"></table>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: thank you so much for this but i'm quite confused are the two codes the same or they are diffrent i would really appreciate an explanantion of some sort.thanks

Comment: Both are same, somehow it got duplicated. What kind of explanation do you need? You can ask me if you have any confusion.

Comment: this is the error Uncaught ReferenceError: loadTable is not defined
    at onload (test.html:144)

Comment: Copy paste the initial code snippet and try to run again in html file. It must run with out any error.  If your still getting error then replace es6 function syntax for onload() with this:
   function loadTable () {
      table.append(getTableHeaderRow());
      showData();
    };